# Files and Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

So in python class we are going over files and exceptions but the professor didn't explain it thoroughly hence why I'm lost to what exactly it is that he wants me to do, I would appreciate any help please. I understand that he wants us to copy the table 2 example but not quite sure. Here is the question.

The file ALW.txt contains the information shown in Table 1. Write a program to use the file to produce a text file containing the information in Table 2, in which the baseball teams list W-L percentage, as well as the total percentage.

---

```
 Table 1:
ALW,W,L,W-L%
----------------
Oakland Athletics,96,66
----------------------
Texas Rangers,91,72
-------------------
Los Angeles,78,84
-------------------
Seattle Mariners,71,91
-----------------------
Houston Astros,51,111
---------------------------
```

Table 2:

```
-----
**Team.........................................W L W-L%**
-----
Oakland Athletics....................96           66       0.593
--------
Texas Rangers.........................91           72       0.558
------
Los Angeles.............................78           84       0.481
--------
Seattle Mariners.......................71           91       0.438
--------
Houston Astros.......................51          111       0.315
--------
Total:........................................387          423       0.484
```

so I came up with this code but I don't think I'm doing it right.

```
fob= open("C:/Users/Manny/Documents/Chapter 5 Assignments/ALW.txt","r")
fob.readline()
print ("Total number of teams: 5 ")
print ("Teams")

Oakland_Athletics_win = 96
Texas_Rangers_win = 91
Los_Angeles_win = 78
Seattle_Mariners_win = 71
Houston_Astros_win = 51
Oakland_Athletics_lose = 66
Texas_Rangers_lose = 72
Los_Angeles_lose = 84
Seattle_Mariners_lose = 91
Houston_Astros_lose = 111
total_win = Oakland_Athletics_win + Texas_Rangers_win + Los_Angeles_win + Seattle_Mariners_win + Houston_Astros_win
total_lose = Oakland_Athletics_lose + Texas_Rangers_lose + Los_Angeles_lose + Seattle_Mariners_lose + Houston_Astros_lose
win_lose_ratio = (Oakland_Athletics_lose + Oakland_Athletics_win)
win_lose_ratio2 = Oakland_Athletics_win / win_lose_ratio
total_ratio = total_win + total_lose
total_ratio2 = total_win / total_ratio

for line in fob:
    x = line.split(",")
    x2 = win_lose_ratio2
    print ('\t','\t','\t','\t',"Wins",'\t',"Losses",'\t','\t',"Win-Lose%")
    print (x[0],'\t',x[1],'\t',x[2],'\t','\t',(x2)) 
print ("Total: ",'\t','\t',total_win,'\t',total_lose,'\t',total_ratio2)
```

Comment: Please read either the [Python 2 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) or the [Python 3 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). Feel free to skim and scan to find the sections you really need and when you have a *specific programming problem* or *difficulty understanding a specific concept*, you may ask about it on Stack Overflow, preferably after posting *what you have already tried* (hint: this means actual code) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

He basically wants you to convert how the statistics are displayed from one file and copy it to a different file in a different format.

I'd suggest that you first read the first file line by line and then split the line with commas. Then the elements at each index of the returned array can be formatted and written to an out file in the format he wants you to.

Answer (score 0):

You teacher wants you to parse the file and produce a similar result than table 2 has.

You will need to:

- open the file
- Go through each line until you find the first Team
- Add the strings separated by commas in that line to a list
- Calculate the percentages
- Carry on till the end
- Write everything in anew file

It's a good exercise and Python is really good doing it

Comment: you lost me when after you said to go through each line until I find the first team... so I opened the file but opened it line by line

Comment: Well, yeah... You need to skip blank lines, if they exist, and that  "Table 1:
ALW,W,L,W-L%"... :D